# Unsigned Character in C

Tags: c

```
unsigned char num;
unsigned char b0=1;
unsigned char b1=0;
unsigned char b2=1;
```

How to assign num to `b2b1b0`?
If we print num in binary at the end, it should be 101.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide with the full code (i do not know where `x` come from) and tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What are b2 b1 b0? Are they single bits?

Comment: There shouldn't be any x.
I just realize << only shifting to the left

Comment: `num = b2 * 4 + b1 * 2 + b2;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming b0, b1, and b2 are all bits within the `num` variable, and assuming little-endianness:

```
num = 1 | 4;
```

If you really needed to use the `b*` variables (I'm assuming you don't), You could do this:

```
unsigned char b0 = 1U;
unsigned char b1 = 2U;
unsigned char b2 = 4U;
unsigned char num = b0 | b2;
```

Comment: Can you explain what's 1 | 4 in c? Thanks

Comment: The number 1 *bitwise-or*'ed with the number 4, or, in binary, '`1` or `100`' -- which equals `101`.

Comment: `1 | 4` indicates a bitwise OR operation between the two values. Written in binary as three bits each, this is `001 | 100`. The OR operation makes a new value, keeping the `1` bits wherever they occur. In this case the result is `101` which is 5 in decimal. Hopefully that makes sense of `1 | 4 = 5`. Coincidentaly the result here is the same as adding them would be, but can you see that `1 | 5 = 5` too?

Comment: b* variables are unknown.
b* are the LSBs from 3 different random numbers